# Adding script in Docker File that starts when the container starts

Tags: java, dockerfile

I have been trying to write the docker file for my Java application. How i can add start_service.sh in Docker file which will execute when the docker container starts running.

Comment: Could you provide the Docker file you already have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may help u solve the problem

```
...
COPY start_service.sh start_service.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["./start_service.sh"]
...
```

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ENTRYPOINT` docker command for this purpose, it will run the script on container start.
Example:

```
FROM ...
...
COPY start_service.sh start_service.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "./start_service.sh"]
```

In this case, the script `start_service.sh` will be executed on the container start.